# Yahoo Chat in Python

Tags: python, networking

I'm wondering how the best way to build a way to interface with Yahoo Chat is.  I haven't found anything that looks incredibly easy to do yet.  One thought it to build it all from scratch, the other thought would be to grab the code from open source software.  I could use something like zinc, however, this maybe more complex than it needs to be.  Another option would be to find a library that supports it, however, I haven't seen one.  What are your thoughts on how to proceed and what would be the best way?  I'm not necessarily looking for the fastest way as this is a bit of a learning project for me.

Comment: By "Yahoo Chat" do you mean Yahoo!Messenger? http://messenger.yahoo.com/

Comment: Not really.  Yahoo chat isn't the same as Yahoo Messenger, but Yahoo messenger can connect to Yahoo Chat.  Basically, it depends on what the library supports if I can do it or not.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I rememeber; you mean the Java chatroom client. Hmm.. It appears that that still uses the YMSG protocol - which means that the Y!M libraries should work... I'll poke around some more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python-purple](https://github.com/fahhem/python-purple) is a python API for accessing libpurple, the Pidgin backend. It will give you access to all the IM networks which Pidgin supports, including Y!Messenger, MSN Messenger, Jabber/GTalk/XMPP, and more...

Comment: Ditto, @William, thanks for the update and the amusement... Apparently the old site got reclaimed some time ago...

Comment: Haha no problem. I saw that and was like O_O and my first thought was omg my wife won't ever believe me when she accidentally finds it in my browser history 3 months from now.